# requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS

Tags: android, android-contacts

Here you can see the details of the exception
[image]

**when I tried to run in my phone it worked fine but on the nexus tab it is showing error  and my manifest.xml file code follows

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zolipe.www.contactsloader">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**

thanks in advance.

Comment: give `WRITE_CONTACTS` permission also

Comment: please add the complete logcat report at the time of exception in the question

Comment: Please add the stack trace as plain text, so others can find google it up.

Answer (score 3):

What's your targetSdkVersion? If it's 23, you need to ask the user for permission. If you don't, you will get this error even though you have correct `uses-permission` tag in manifest. See http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html.

If you don't want to change the code now, set targetSdkVersion to 22. In this case, all permissions will be granted at install time.